# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float;

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I am having a problem with there error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float
```

on this line of my code below:

```
a1[j+1] = key
```

Here is my code below:

```
a1 = [4.3, 5.2, 5.0, 1.5, 3.8, 4.1, 5.5, 1.9]
sum = 0
count = len(a1)
for i in a1:
    sum = sum + float(i)
    key = a1[index]
    j = i-1
    while j >= 0 and key < j : 
        a1[j + 1] = a1[j] 
        j -= 1
    a1[j+1] = key 
mean = sum/count
print("Answer for y = 1.5")
print("Average: {0}".format(mean))
```

I want an insertion sort to sort the array a1

Comment: `i` is the list element, not its index. So `j = i-1` doesn't give you a place to insert.

Comment: What is `index` in `a1[index]`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a `while` loop instead of `a1.insert()`?

Comment: If you want to find out how to do insertion sort, search SO for "[python] insertion sort"

Answer (score 0):

For insertion sort you can try this. However for finding out the total using the your method will result into wrong ans since a1 is getting modified at each iterations and will result in incorect calculation of total. Instead you can use **sum()** method provided by python to calculate the total of the list.

```
a1 = [4.3, 5.2, 5.0, 1.5, 3.8, 4.1, 5.5, 1.9]
total = 0
count = len(a1)
for i in range(1, len(a1)):
    key = a1[i] 
    j = i-1
    while j >=0 and key < a1[j] : 
        a1[j+1] = a1[j] 
        j -= 1
    a1[j+1] = key

total =sum(a1)
mean = total/count
print("Answer for y = 1.5")
print("Average: {0}".format(mean))
print(a1)
```

Output :

```
Answer for y = 1.5
Average: 3.9124999999999996
[1.5, 1.9, 3.8, 4.1, 4.3, 5.0, 5.2, 5.5]
```